# using numpy to randomly distribute DNA sequence reads over genomic features

Tags: python, random, numpy, sequence

Hi I have written a script that randomly shuffles read sequences over the gene they were mapped to.
This is useful if you want to determine if a peak that you observe over your gene of interest is statistically significant. I use this code to calculate False Discovery Rates for peaks in my gene of interest.
Below the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iterations = 1000 # number of times a read needs to be shuffled
featurelength = 1000  # length of the gene
a = np.zeros((iterations,featurelength))  # create a matrix with 1000 rows of the feature length
b = np.arange(iterations)                 # a matrix with the number of iterations (0-999)
reads = np.random.randint(10,50,1000)     # a random dataset containing an array of DNA read lengths
```

Below the code to fill the large matrix (a):

```
for i in reads:               # for read with read length i
    r = np.random.randint(-i,featurelength-1,iterations) # generate random read start positions for the read i
    for j in b:               # for each row in a:
        pos = r[j]            # get the first random start position for that row
        if pos < 0:           # start position can be negative because a read does not have to completely overlap with the feature
            a[j][:pos+i]+=1
        else:
            a[j][pos:pos+i]+=1  # add the read to the array and repeat
```

Then generate a heat map to see if the distribution is roughly even:

```
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

This generates the desired result but it is very slow because of the many for loops.
I tried to do fancy numpy indexing but I constantly get the "too many indices error".

Anybody have a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what the loop is meant to be doing? For example, I don't understand why you generate `r` and then only use one of its elements. Couldn't you just generate `pos` directly?

Comment: So r has 1000 random numbers which essentially are random start positions for read i. So for the first row j in matrix a, the start position for the read is r[j]. What I would like to do is change the whole matrix in one go essentially but for some reason numpy won't allow me to do this. What you can do is : `a[(j,pos)]+=1`. You can also do `a[(j,tuple(range(pos,pos+1)))]+=1`. However, when you do this for all the random positions in r: `a[(j,tuple(range(pos,pos+i))),(j2,tuple(range(pos2,pos2+i)))]+=1`, etc then it complains `IndexError, too many indices` or something

Comment: I don't think fancyindexing supports slicing by start:end arrays, only by integers. That pretty much breaks up any further attempts at vectorization I fear.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: just convert your start:end slices into integer arrays with `arange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancy indexing is a bit tricky, but still possible:

```
for i in reads:
    r = np.random.randint(-i,featurelength-1,iterations)
    idx = np.clip(np.arange(i)[:,None]+r, 0, featurelength-1)
    a[b,idx] += 1
```

To deconstruct this a bit, we're:

1. Creating a simple index array as a column vector, from 0 to i: `np.arange(i)[:,None]`
2. Adding each element from `r` (a row vector), which broadcasts to make a matrix of size `(i,iterations)` with the correct offsets into the columns of `a`.
3. Clamping the indices to the range `[0,featurelength)`, via `np.clip`.
4. Finally, we fancy-index `a` for each row (`b`) and the relevant columns (`idx`).

Comment: np.clip would be more concise.

Comment: My code: 1 loops, best of 3: 3.6 s per loop perimosocordiae's code: 1 loops, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop. Roughly 3x faster and produces the exact same result. Thanks!!!